# Sequence of data inside dataset not maintained while inserting to table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am selecting data from Excel sheet and inserting to a table. When I read data from Excel to dataset the sequence of data is same as Excel sheet. I am inserting data row by row using foreach loop in table as follows:

```
  foreach (DataRow drow in Dset.Tables["TABLE1"].Rows)
  {
          // passing row and inserting data using procedure
  }
  // Is foreach loop selecting the rows randomly??
```

All data is inserted but the sequence of rows is somewhat changed. Because of wrong sequence I am getting wrong results in my app. Why so? I am not able to understand why the sequence is changes automatically.

Comment: The sequence is not changed, but it could help to show the code which fills the table.

Comment: Where do you see them in the wrong order? If in the database, what is the  schema and the query that you use to select the records?

Comment: The sequence is fine in dataset.same as excel sheet.                        SELECT top 1000 * FROM [" + sheetName + "] is the query for selecting data.when i insert it row by row i see in databse that the sequence is changed for ex row no. 7 is inserted before 5 etc

Comment: So where is it wrong then? Do you have a primary key in your table or another column used for ordering? Note that a table has no inherent order.

Comment: What sort of table are you inserting into - a .net DataTable or a database table. If the latter then you cannot guarantee the order the data is retrieved by an SQL query (unless you have an ORDER By clause) : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/why-is-ssms-inserting-new-rows-at-the-top-of-a-table-not-the-bottom/5775#5775

Comment: No my table doesnt have any primary key ot autoincremented unique key

Comment: I am inserting from .net datatable to sql server table

Comment: @Pwavel002: but how do you watch  your data? You have to use an `ORDER BY`. A datatabase table is not a sequential collection but an unordered set, the order is not predictable unless you specify it. Without an `ORDER BY ` you might today get the insertition order but a different order tomorrow.

Comment: A relational table **has NO ordering** per se - there **is NO order** by default. You only get an ordering if you use a `ORDER BY` in your select - so there's no *wrong order* when inserting data - the ordering **only** happens when you select from that table with an `ORDER BY` clause.